# Converting image to base64 gives the same output on every image (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, base64

I'm trying to encode image with base64 like this:

```
var image = localStorage.getItem("image");
alert(image);
function readImage(url, callback) {
    var request = new
    XMLHttpRequest(); request.onload = function () {
        var file = new FileReader();
        file.onloadend = function () {
            callback(file.result);
        }
        file.readAsDataURL(request.response);
    };
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'blob';
    request.send();
}

readImage(image, function (base64) {
    localStorage.setItem("Base64", base64);
});
var base64_2 = localStorage.getItem("Base64");
```

It gives me the same base64 output on every picture link I get from localStorage (Checked it, the images from localStorage are different).

What is the problem?

Comment: Because you are not waiting for the data to load. `var base64_2 = localStorage.getItem("Base64");` runs _before_ `localStorage.setItem("Base64", base64);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting `base64` because of `Async` code inside `readImage`. `XMLHttpRequest` and `FileReader` both works in `Async` manner due to this your bottom code execute first after that It will come in `callback`

```
readImage(image, function (base64) {
    localStorage.setItem("Base64", base64);
    successHandler();  //successHandler will call when callback return base64 after processing
});

function successHandler(){
    var base64_2 = localStorage.getItem("Base64");
}
```